# Passing objects in ItemsControl using a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

So basically I have a class Step.

```
public class Step : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
}
```

In my xaml, I want to represent Steps using one DataTemplate and an ItemsControl. My DataTemplate looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StepTemplate" DataType="data:Step">
    <Label Content="{Binding Index}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Time}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And my ItemsControl looks like this.

```
<ItemsControl Name="ListSteps" ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StepTemplate}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.StepClick, ElementName=ListSteps}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ItemsControl>
```

**So pretty much what should happen:** Whenever I click on a `Step`, the method `StepClick` gets called and the Step object that I clicked on is passed as a parameter.

**What is actually happening:** Whenever I click on a `Step`, the method `StepClick` gets called, but not the Step Object gets passed as a parameter but an object of my view gets passed. Which is not at all what I want.

How can I pass an object of `Step` whenever I click on a `Step`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the interaction trigger to the root element of the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StepTemplate" DataType="data:Step">
    <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.StepClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Label Content="{Binding Index}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Time}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```